# Optimize performance for transposing values to 0 and 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

Let's say we have a list of employees and some other data:

```
  Employee   Location   Title
0        1  Location1  Title1
1        2  Location2  Title1
2        3  Location3  Title2
3        4  Location1  Title3
4        5  Location1  Title2
```

I am transposing it to features and labels with (1,0) values, and it works but it takes ages on databased of 6k records. Logic: take value from Location, make it a column, if employees location matches column put 1, else put 0.

**My question: is it possible to optimize performance somehow? My lacking of terminology makes it difficult to find the better solution, but I believe that something should be there.**

The final output looks like this:

```
 Employee  Location1  Location2  Location3  Title1  Title2  Title3
0        1          1          0          0       1       0       0
1        2          0          1          0       1       0       0
2        3          0          0          1       0       1       0
3        4          1          0          0       0       0       1
4        5          1          0          0       0       1       0
```

The working code that takes ages to complete:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Employee': ['1','2','3','4','5'], 
      'Location': ['Location1', 'Location2','Location3','Location1','Location1'],
      'Title': ['Title1','Title1','Title2','Title3','Title2']
     })
df_tr = df['Employee'] #temporary employee ids

# transposing the data, which takes ages:

df_newcols = {}
for column in list(df)[1:]:
    newcols = df[column].unique()
    for key in newcols:
        temp_ar = []
        for value in df[column]:
            if key == value:
                temp_ar.append(1)
            else:
                temp_ar.append(0)
        df_newcols[key] = temp_ar
print (df_newcols)

# adding transposed to the temp df

df_temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_newcols)

# merging with df with employee ids

new_df = pd.concat([df_tr,df_temp],axis=1)
```

Comment: Use [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html).

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```py
df["_dummy"]=1
df2=pd.concat([
    df.pivot_table(index="Employee", columns="Location", values="_dummy", aggfunc=max), 
    df.pivot_table(index="Employee", columns="Title", values="_dummy", aggfunc=max)
], axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index(drop=False)
```

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using [`pd.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html#pandas-get-dummies):

```
print( pd.concat([df['Employee'],
                  pd.get_dummies(df['Location']),
                  pd.get_dummies(df['Title'])], axis=1) )
```

Prints:

```
  Employee  Location1  Location2  Location3  Title1  Title2  Title3
0        1          1          0          0       1       0       0
1        2          0          1          0       1       0       0
2        3          0          0          1       0       1       0
3        4          1          0          0       0       0       1
4        5          1          0          0       0       1       0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use more the "apply" methods and the methods of pandas in general.   Using "for loops" in pandas is very bad... it kills your performance.

A possible solution is the following:

```
import pandas as pd


# read the file
emp=pd.read_csv("employee_huge.txt", sep=" ")


# generate unique lists containing LocationX and TitleX
lnewcols_location=set(emp["Location"].to_list())
lnewcols_title=set(emp["Title"].to_list())


# a function to compare a cell (like "Location1") to a string that is the name of the column
# like "Location2".  If they match return 1, otherwise 0
def same_as_col(acell, col):
    if(acell==col):
        return(1)
    else:
        return(0)


# generate all the LocationN columns with 1 or 0 if there is a match
for i in lnewcols_location:
  emp[i]=emp["Location"].apply(same_as_col, col=i)

# generate all the TitleN columns with 1 or 0 if there is a match
for i in lnewcols_title:
  emp[i]=emp["Title"].apply(same_as_col, col=i)

# removing Location and Title columns
emp=emp.drop(["Location", "Title"], axis=1)
```

A final note, I generated a file called employee_huge.txt.  It's content is formatted like the following:

```
Employee Location Title
0 Location4 Title1
1 Location1 Title3
2 Location1 Title2
3 Location1 Title4
4 Location4 Title1
```

Comment: All correct, except- you should avoid ```.apply(...)```: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/11610186

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am also new of pandas so my solution is not optimal like yours. 
Although It works in a second.  I will replace apply with list comprehension when possible in the future.